# Plotting by ignoring missing data in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have been trying to make a program that plots the frequency of usage of a word during Whatsapp chats between 2 people. The word `night` for example has been used a couple of times on a few days, and 0 times on the most of the days. The graph I have is as follows

[image: Usage of the word night]

Here is the code

```py
word_occurances = [0 for i in range(len(just_dates))]

for i in range(len(just_dates)):
    for j in range(len(df_word)):
        if just_dates[i].date() == word_date[j].date():
            word_occurances[i] += 1

title = person2.rstrip(':') + ' with ' + person1.rstrip(':') + ' usage of the word - ' + word

plt.plot(just_dates, word_occurances, color = 'purple')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('number of times used')
plt.title(title)
plt.savefig('Graphs/Words/' + title + '.jpg', dpi = 200)
plt.show()
```

word_occurances is a list

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

What I want is for the graph to only connect the points where it has been used while showing the entire timeline on the x axis. I don't want the graph to touch 0. How can I do this? I have searched and found similar answers but none have worked the way I them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to find the indices of `word_occurances` on which the corresponding value is greater than zero. With this you can index `just_dates` to get the corresponding dates.

```
word_counts = []    # Only word counts > 0
dates = []          # Date of > 0 word count
for i, val in enumerate(word_occurances):
    if val > 0:
        word_counts.append(val)
        dates.append(just_dates[i])
```

You may want to plot with an underlying bar plot in order to maintain the original scale.

```
plt.bar(just_dates, word_occurances)
plt.plot(dates, word_counts, 'r--')
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to address this is to plot only data that contain entries but label all dates where a conversation took place to indicate the zero values in your graph:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator

#fake data generation, this block just imitates your unknown data and can be deleted
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(12345)
n = 30
just_dates = pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(1, 100, n)+18500, unit="D").sort_values().to_list()
word_occurances = [0]*n
for i in range(10): 
    word_occurances[np.random.randint(n)] = np.random.randint(1, 10)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))

#generate data to plot by filtering out zero values
plot_data = [(just_dates[i], word_occurances[i]) for i, num in enumerate(word_occurances) if num > 0]

#plot these data with marker to indicate each point 
#think 1-1-1-1-1 would only be visible as two points with lines only
ax.plot(*zip(*plot_data), color = 'purple', marker="o")
#label all dates where conversations took place
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(mdates.date2num(just_dates)))
#prevent that matplotlib autoscales the y-axis
ax.set_ylim(0, )
ax.tick_params(axis="x", labelrotation= 90)

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('number of times used')
plt.title("Conversations at night")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image: ![enter image description here]

This can get quite busy soon with all these date labels (and might or might not work with your datetime objects in `just_dates` that might differ in structure from my sample date). Another way would be to indicate each conversation with [`vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html):

```
...
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))

plot_data = [(just_dates[i], word_occurances[i]) for i, num in enumerate(word_occurances) if num > 0]

ax.plot(*zip(*plot_data), color = 'purple', marker="o")
ax.vlines((just_dates), 0, max(word_occurances), color="red", ls="--")
ax.set_ylim(0, )

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('number of times used')
plt.title("Conversations at night")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]